# cell uptake prediction

Tags: cell-membrane, organic-chemistry

I'm generating random molecules I would like to know if they are able to pass through the cell membrane. Are there any ways (preferably computational) to predict cellular uptake of an organic molecule which is about 55 atoms?

Comment: If it's polar, it's not going through. If it's non-polar, there's a good chance it will diffuse through...

Comment: cLogP? I would imagine that's a fast dirty way to get an estimate. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_coefficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absorption, distribution, metabolism, excretion, and toxicity ADMET can be somewhat computationally defined but is largely secretive due to the money involved in drug discovery. [FAF-Drugs2](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2105/9/396) will do basic ADMET. The [Schordinger Suit](http://www.schrodinger.com/productpage/14/17/) provides a more indepth ADMET for a fee.